# How can a custom jquery plugin use a no-conflict library?

Tags: jquery

I need to load 2 different versions of jQuery libraries. To my first library loaded, I want to "attach" the capty plugin.

```
;(function($) {
     //foo
}(jQuery)
```

So, I load my first library, load jquery-ui.js and jquery-migrate.js and afterwards I immediately rename the global variable $ to jq10

```
<script>
     var jq10 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Subsequently, I open the jquery.capty.js and change jQuery to jq10.

```
;(function($) {
     //foo
}(jq10)
```

Afterwards the second jquery library (different version) is loaded.

Loading the page, reports `Selector invalid or missing!` and points to the new assigne variable jq10 in the jquery.capty.js file.

How can you use jq10 in those plugins?

(btw, if capty plugin on $ it will report that capty() is not a function, if I want to use that method - that is because I need to load the latter jQuery library at the very end of the head tag. So, not an option.)

Comment: You have to be sure that the jq10 is set before the plugin is loaded. That doesn't seem to be the case. Try to put the jq10 = jQuery.noConflict(true) into a seperate js file which is included before you call your plugins.

Comment: did not help. Same error: Selector invalid or missing! However, I notice, this is an error from the capty library. So, it always worked. Also the hint from @schlingel works.